# Weird behavior with instance variable - cannot access at certain times

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I ran into a strange error where a PFObject that was an instance variable of my class (ImagePostStructure) would strangely be nonexistent if I checked for its existence in a closure. In addition, doing a reference to that variable via an external variable from inside the closure would fix that issue when ran, but the PFObject instance var would still disappear and be unable to be accessed at all later on.

The below is the relevant part of my class that initializes PFObject:

```
class ImagePostStructure {

    var myObj: PFObject?
    var image: UIImage?
    ...other variables...
    init(inputObj: PFObject) {
        //called when retrieving object (for viewing, etc)
        myObj = inputObj;
        ...
    }
```

And the below is a method in the same class, where I am loading a image file from my PFObject.

```
func loadImage(finishFunction: (imgStruct: ImagePostStructure, index: Int)->Void, index: Int) {
    if (!image) {
        var imgFile: PFFile = myObj!["imageFile"] as PFFile;
        //comment immediate line below
        var obj = self.myObj;   //<----setting an external reference for my closure
        imgFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock( { (result: NSData!, error: NSError!) in
            if (!error) {
                //get file objects
                self.image = UIImage(data: result);
                NSLog("This runs: \(self)");

                //comment immediate line below
                NSLog("This also runs \(obj)");  //<----commenting this causes error

                NSLog("This does NOT run if above is NOT commented \(self.myObj!)");
                NSLog("This does NOT run if above is NOT commented \(self.myObj!.objectId)");

                finishFunction(imgStruct: self, index: index);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        finishFunction(imgStruct: self, index: index);
    }
}
```

If I comment the line referencing the PFObject instance variable in the NSLog, then I can no longer access the PFObject instance variable from self. Whenever I try to access "myObj", whether internally from inside the class or outside, the error I get is:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

Before, when I had my 'myObj' not be an optional variable before, the error I got was something along the lines of:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)
```

I would, preferably, not want to program in this manner, as I keep using "myObj" elsewhere in my program and it disappearing off the face of the Earth has caused me many problems beyond this method.

I've done a text search on where "myObj" is being set or moved, and it is only being read in the rest of program (and erroring wherever I read it a bit after I make the object). I've also done a check on whether "myObj" is nil at that point of execution, and it errors up trying to read the variable (so "if (self.myObj)..." errors up). The variable explorer on the bottom left side shows that self has a myObj at that time so I don't think it is getting set to nil either.

I've tried looking up both errors. For the 2nd, I've only found a few obscure instances that seem irrelevant, and the first just seems to imply a general error with misaligned addresses.

This code also worked in Xcode 6 beta 3 previously (I upgraded to 4 today), so it must also be an issue/thing that Xcode6 beta 4 did...any help would be appreciated

EDIT: I'm suspecting it is an ARC error, since the code errors not always at the same line. For some reason I suspect that PFObject is being dereferenced and de-alloced even though my class has a strong connection to it...

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your error, but you are using a non-weak reference to `self` within your closure, which will cause a strong reference cycle, as outlined here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_99

Answer (score 0):

which SDK are you using?
I noticed Xcode6B4 has a bug where accessing instance variables is a problem and sometimes not possible.  There are a couple of threads in the apple developer forums.

Have you tried it with Xcode6B3?

Comment: for now I'm using it with Xcode6B3, it works perfectly there. I'm putting aside the error for now to continue development, will update this thread eventually when I go back to updating or when 6B5 comes out. I'm 99% sure it's a deallocation error due to a variable I'm using inside the closure being deallocated when I get to run the closure.